# Unable to connect to Neo4j with rusted_cypher

Tags: rust, neo4j, serde

I am trying to use Neo4j with Rust. Currently, there is no official driver. I've been trying to connect with the rusted_cypher crate, to no avail. I've used Neo4j extensively with Python but I am new to Rust.

Here is the minimal example:

Cargo.toml

```
rusted_cypher = "1.1.0"
```

main.rs

```
use rusted_cypher::GraphClient;

fn main() {
    
    let graph = GraphClient::connect(
        "http://<username>:<password>@localhost:7474/<database_name>/data").unwrap();

}
```

This returns:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Serde(Error("EOF while parsing a value", line: 1, column: 0))', src/main.rs:6:53
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

When I try to remove the database name I get:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Serde(Error("missing field `extensions`", line: 0, column: 0))', src/main.rs:6:49
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Comment: Can you try to remove the database name?

Comment: I have removed the database name, which also returns an error (I've edited the question to reflect that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that rusted cypher doesn't work anymore with the changed database URLs, which are now `http(s)//:host:7474/db/<database>/tx`

But I found these two drivers that look more promising, recently updated and using bolt:

https://github.com/lucis-fluxum/bolt-rs

https://github.com/yehohanan7/neo4rs

docs: https://docs.rs/neo4rs/0.5.8/neo4rs/